# How to practically apply Lewandowski algorithm?

Tags: forecasting, algorithms, forecastability

I am studying forecasting based on Lewandowski algorithm. I have an [article](https://www.dropbox.com/s/x3m2lkqrrsbq6tx/Lewandowski%20algorithm.pdf?dl=0) that introduces about Lewandowski algorithm, but I do not understand how to apply in practical, especially model it in Excel file. Explanation on this would be appreciated.

Comment: The Lewandowski algorithm is *ancient*, practically nowhere documented (it certainly is not discussed in any forecasting textbook published in the last 30 years), and to my knowledge never applied. On the one hand, you will likely not find any more information on it here or elsewhere. On the other hand, why do you want to look at this particular algorithm in the first place? Exponential smoothing, for instance, is much better understood, studied, explained and implemented in standard software. See https://otexts.com/fpp3/.

Comment: I want it because it gets high evalatiation from many M-Competition and is using in JDA Demand planning

Comment: Hm. I just went and searched for "Lewandowski" in the results papers of the M2, M3, M4 and M5 competitions (I don't have access to the M1 paper from 1982(!)). The Lewandowski algorithm is mentioned nowhere, so I'm not sure where you got that idea. Yes, it is supposedly used by JDA, but (a) documentation is extremely sparse, so it's hard to say how much it is really used, and (b) this may simply be due to the fact that users *extremely* dislike changing forecasting algorithms they have been using for decades, because the consequences may be unpredictable.

Comment: So, unless your objective is to reconstruct an ancient methodology (maybe you are working in an environment with a very old forecasting system), I would still recommend using a more modern method. In any case, you will likely not find a lot of information on the Lewandowski algorithm, per above. If it's a question of better understanding an installed JDA system, you could always contact their support (but judging from long painful experience in a large software company, there may be very little useful documentation, even if they are willing to hand it out).